# how to get the background color of a view to save it in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

> With seekbar I can change background color but cannot save shanged
>   color when open activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("COLOR", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("color_KEY",  );   //?? what code for this?
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red.getProgress(), green.getProgress(),blue.getProgress()));
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: editor.putInt("color_KEY", button.getSolidColor());

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this `class` to pass your view and get the color code. then you can save it as you want with your colour_Key!

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Rect mBounds;

    public void initIfNeeded() {
      if(mBitmap == null) {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        mBounds = new Rect();
      }
    }

    public int getBackgroundColor(View view) {
      // The actual color, not the id.
      int color = Color.BLACK;

      if(view.getBackground() instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
          initIfNeeded();

          // If the ColorDrawable makes use of its bounds in the draw method,
          // we may not be able to get the color we want. This is not the usual
          // case before Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0.1 r1).
          // Yet, we change the bounds temporarily, just to be sure that we are
          // successful.
          ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable)view.getBackground();

          mBounds.set(colorDrawable.getBounds()); // Save the original bounds.
          colorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1); // Change the bounds.

          colorDrawable.draw(mCanvas);
          color = mBitmap.getPixel(0, 0);

          colorDrawable.setBounds(mBounds); // Restore the original bounds.
        }
        else {
          color = ((ColorDrawable)view.getBackground()).getColor();
        }
      }

      return color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("COLOR", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
// Only if you know it is a color
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
editor.putInt("color_KEY", colorId  );
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way,

`ColorDrawable buttonColor =(ColorDrawable)button.getBackground();
     int colorId = buttonColor.getColor();
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("COLOR",MODE_PRIVATE);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
     editor.putInt("color_KEY",id.toString()); 
     editor.commit();`